# Upload image to web server and store path in database

Tags: php, html, mysql, linux, webserver

I am trying to upload image to my webserver using php and to store the path of image in mysql database, I'm not able to do this. Any help would be appreciated. When I hit submit, I could see a blank php page..

***post.php***

```
<?php


$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";

$name = $_POST['ctitle'];
$description = $_POST['cdesc'];
$image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$filepath = "images/";
$filepath = $filepath . basename($image);

if(move_uploaded_file($image, $filepath)){
$con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $con )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql="INSERT INTO bbmp (dt,title,description,filename,img_path)
VALUES (NOW(), '$name','$description','$image','$filepath')";

mysql_select_db('bbmp',$con);
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $con );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($con);
}

?>
```

***index.html***

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
</head>
<body>
        <h1>Post your complaints here</h1>
        <form method="POST" action="post.php">
                <input type="name" name="ctitle"><br />
                <textarea name="cdesc"></textarea><br />
                <input type="file" name="image" ><br />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

***sql***

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bbmp` (
  `id` int(100) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `img_path` int(255) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: white page of death, error reporting\display are off, turn them on `error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a valid enctype when uploading files: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Change it to:

```
  <form method="POST" action="post.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

you need change variable to this too because $_FILES['image']['name'] is just a name, so put this to run move_uploaded_file() function

```
 $image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
```

Comment: I tried this.. And still doesn't work. Blank page with no errors.

Comment: i tested with your code and worked, try put :
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: you need change $image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: image in /var/www/html/test/upload/post.php on line 10
This was the error, when i changed to 
$image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

Comment: i have same error if not use enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: I have used   <form method="POST" action="post.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

and $image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

and same error

Comment: what's the a.php you have included in the form action?

Comment: just create file a.php and paste from that pastebin